# Loop URLs from mySQL database iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift, hyperlink

I have a list of locations. 
When a user taps a location, I want its respective website to load.

[image: labels]

I am pulling the locations and the URLs from a mySQL database - and the results are in JSON. http://wiu.edu/CITR/mywesternios/test.sphp

[image: JSON data]

I'm using the code below to make the URL (currently showing wiu.edu everytime a location is tapped). **Below is the code to adjust.**

[image: code to change]

**How can I get myURL to change for each location?**

Comment: in prepare for segue put url from tableview item to detail controller variable

Answer (score 0):

In DetailViewController add new property to store selected value
`var urlString: String!` (for example) and on Your table view controller set this value in prepareForSegue method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue_identifier" {
            let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            detailVC.urlString = selectedURL
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Please see the following screenshots.  <br> 1. How do I get the URL from the JSON data in ViewController.swift?  2. How do I use this URL in DetailViewController.swift?https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_csnGVoTtBxYjVEYkNQVmxwaFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: take a look if you would